# Error 9 with If Left

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting run error time 9 and i have no idea why. Some info is:

Sheet 1 is special customers

Sheet 2 is copied PDF with invoices

```
Public Sub TestMe()

Dim r1      As Variant

Dim rData   As Variant
Dim r       As Variant
Dim result  As Variant

Dim i       As Integer

rData = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(2).Range("A:A"))
r1 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("C2:C33"))

For Each r In r1
  result = Application.Match(r, rData, 0)  ' returns row of matching customer
  If Not IsError(result) Then  ' found customer, now look for "418"
    For i = 1 To 4
      If Left(Trim(rData(result - i, 3)), 1) = "418" Then
        MsgBox rData(result - i, 1)
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next r

End Sub
```

So I'm getting this error at `If Left(Trim(rData(result - i, 3)), 1) = "418" Then`. I'm trying to get invoice number from `rData`, that starts with `418`, which is copied PDF with invoices for customer and `r1` is a customer with special needs (it goes up to `r50`). The issue is that invoice nr is between 1 and 4 celles above found customer name (which is `r`).

Comment: So which line gives error? This portion `rData(result - i, 3)` can probably give error if result index is less than 4.

Comment: What kind of data is Range A:A? What kind of data is range C2:C33? What are you trying to accomplish?  The line that fails is the `If Left`? Have you tried debugging? What is the value of `result,i,rdata` when it fails? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just out of interest, when could `left(anything,1)` give you `"418"`?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij i edited my post with better explanation, i hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rData` is a 1-dimensional array:

```
rData = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(2).Range("A:A"))
```

You are trying to get the 2. dimension of a 1-dimensional array. It gives you an error:

```
rData(result - i, 3)
```